# How to convert this string to an interable list of Python files in Bash?

Tags: bash

I have a string as follows:

```
string = '[ "file1.py", "file2.py", "file3.py", "file4.py" ]'
```

How to convert it to an iterable list of individual filenames so that I can run a for loop on it as follows:

```
for filen in fileArr
do
    echo $filen
done
```

Expected output:

```
file1.py
file2.py
file3.py
file4.py
```

So far I have just removed the first and last square brackets using `string=${string:1:${#string}-2}` but I still have quotations and commas to remove. Is there a clean and simple way to achieve this?

Comment: @Z4-tier Yes, my mouse is not working recently. I might have clicked twice. Deleted the other post. Thanks for highlighting.

Comment: @user3243499 you're [not the only one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289598/should-i-flag-my-own-double-posted-answer) this happens to, and you did well to delete the other one. It seems weird that these duplicates aren't caught automatically TBH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `tr` command (more information about the tr command [here](https://linuxhint.com/bash_tr_command/)) to eliminate the start bracket, the end bracket, and the double quotations. Also, you can substitute the coma for a tab so you can later iterate the over the result.

Here the code:

```
$ s='[ "file1.py", "file2.py", "file3.py", "file4.py" ]'
$ s2=$(echo $s | tr "[" " " | tr "]" " " | tr "\"" " " | tr "," "\\t")
$ for x in $s2; do echo $x ; done
file1.py
file2.py
file3.py
file4.py
```

More in-depth, the `s2` statement uses:

```
s2=$(          --> Assigns the output of the full command to s2
  echo $s        --> Prints the content of s to the pipes
  | tr "[" " "   --> Substitute the start bracket by spaces
  | tr "]" " "   --> Substitute the end bracket by spaces
  | tr "\"" " "  --> Substitute the double quotations by spaces
  | tr "," "\\t"  --> Substitute the comma by a tab
)
```

Notice that this code is valid for the kind of input you provided but it will not work if the filenames contain spaces.

**EDIT:**

Another solution is possible using [substring replacement](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) instead of using the `tr` command.

Here the code:

```
$ s2=${s//\[/}  # Erase the start brackets
$ s3=${s2//\]/}  # Erase the end brackets
$ s4=${s3//\"/}  # Erase the double quotations
$ s5=${s4//,/ }  # Substitute the comma by a tab
$ for x in $s5; do echo $x ; done
file1.py
file2.py
file3.py
file4.py
```

As the previous solution, notice that the code will not work if the filenames contain spaces (since they will be considered separated entries).

**EDIT 2:**

As @Z4-tier pointed out, the first option can be re-written in a more compact way using the `-d` option available in `tr`. This option erases the given characters. Also, the obtained string after the parsing might not be iterable if the Internal Field Separator (IFS) is set incorrectly. Although I think that the previous solutions cover most of the cases, you might consider setting and restoring the IFS value if it was set to something else than the default value.

Hence, you could write:

```
$ s='[ "file1.py", "file2.py", "file3.py", "file4.py" ]'
$ s2=$(echo $s | tr -d "[]\"" | tr "," "\\t")
$ IFS=$' '
$ for x in $s2; do echo $x ; done
file1.py
file2.py
file3.py
file4.py
$ IFS= #restore your IFS value
```

Comment: This looks clean, could you please explain the `s2` statement. I want to understand how it is working instead of just copying and pasting. Thanks.

Comment: @user3243499 Sure, see my updated answer and ask for any further information if required.

Comment: got it thanks. Was not aware of `tr`. What is it? I am guessing delete character and replace. Is it right or `t` and `r` has separate meanings in `tr`?

Comment: I have added a link to the `tr` description. It is a single bash command `tr` that substitutes a given character for another one. Quite useful tbh

Comment: what happens if you do this: `IFS=$'\n'; echo "${s2[0]}"`.This is creating one string and not an indexed iterable. Try doing this: `for x in $s2; do echo foo $x bar ; done`

Comment: @Z4-tier Sure, if you change the internal field separator then the solution will not work. Same happens if you add filenames with spaces. That said, for me, it looks like a simple environment so I would rather keep it simple too :) Otherwise, you could also consider adding IFS=" " in front of the `echo` command and restore it later, couldn't you?

Comment: setting IFS is not really the point. Doing this: `unset IFS; s='[ "file1.py", "file2.py", "file3.py", "file4.py" ]'; s2=$(echo $s | tr "[" " " | tr "]" " " | tr "\"" " " | tr "," "\\t")` is creating one big string: `echo "${#s2[*]}";` == 1, `"echo "${s2[0]}";` contains the whole string, and `echo "${s2[1]}"` is empty. The loop `for x in $s2; do echo $x ; done` is not using "an iterable list of individual filenames", it is having the shell do word splitting on a string.

Comment: sorry to split hairs on this one, but this tends to be a BIG source of confusion and frustration for those not familiar with some of these less-than-intuitive behaviors in bash.

Comment: I know that you force BASH to do word splitting on the string but I don't see the problem of doing that nor the necessity of using an array to do so. In fact, when you build the array on your solution you are also forcing the bash word splitting...

Comment: But the question specifically asks for an iterable list, both in the title and again in the question itself. This answer may (and probably does) give the OP what they were looking for, but it doesn't actually *answer the question as it is written*. A future visitor may read this and assume that it really does explain how to convert a string to an iterable with Bash. Then they are left in a worse position than before, having been misinformed about something that is already a tremendous source of confusion for quite a few people.

Comment: As far as I know, a bash string is iterable. Thus, this answer still answers the question. Imho you are over-engineering a simple question that does not even require the use of arrays. That said, the person asking this question considered that this answer was useful and accepted it. If someone feels like this is not the right answer feel free to downvote it or vote other answers.

Answer (score -1):

`tr <string1> <string2>` will replace any occurance of a character in `string1` with the character appearing in the same index position from `string2`, so this can be done with 1 pipe.

`tr` can also be used as `tr -d <string1>` where any occurance of a character in `string1` is deleted.

```
s='[ "file1.py", "file2.py", "file3.py", "file4.py" ]'
s2=$(echo $s | tr -d '[]",')
```

This is not iterable like you might think. It is still one string:

```
bash-$ echo "${s2[0]}"
 file1.py file2.py file3.py file4.py
```

Try this:

```
IFS=$' '
bash-$ my_array=($(echo $s | tr -d '[]",'))
bash-$ echo "${my_array[0]}"
file1.py
bash-$ for k in "${my_array[@]}"; do echo $k; done
file1.py
file2.py
file3.py
file4.py
```

This sets `IFS` (the *internal field separator*) to a space character to take advantage of the spaces that are left in the string after it gets run through `tr`. It uses a subshell to translate `s` into what we called `s2` above (now using `my_array` to indicate that it's not a string...), surrounds it with `(...)` to create an indexed array (this is where IFS is important).